# Why was Live PD cancelled?

Tags: production, documentary, cops, live-pd

Instead of removing a show from the air because of racial inequality, why couldn't they just have a more diverse line-up? This is a popular show like COPS. Why did they cancel Live PD?

Comment: The briefest of research indicates that (alongside the fact that protests about police violence are happening all over the globe) controversy has arisen in the last week about the fact that the show destroyed footage of in custody deaths.  This appears on the surface to be in line with the operating practices agreed with police - but in the current circumstances probably doesn't look that great in the public eye.

Comment: @m Polo upvote?

Comment: @iandotkelly Can you make that an asnwer. Could another company pick up where they left off. Or has it been made illegal to have a live PD type show?

Comment: Its not illegal to make a live reality TV show about the police.  Its just not good PR.

Comment: And COPS has been cancelled so not a great example there

Comment: "Why couldn't they just have a more diverse line-up?" - Leaving aside the fact that the show's level of diversity had nothing to do with its cancellation, documentaries just don't work that way. They can only follow the people who are actually there. If the cops are disproportionately white, that's not the program's fault.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Primarily the answer is 'public relations'.  The events of the last few weeks (principally the death of George Floyd) have significantly changed the public perception of the police and the Black Lives Matter movement.

Fairly or unfairly it is now an environment where scripted or reality cop shows are less favorably viewed, therefore less profitable.

In addition to this, it has come to light that [PD Live destroyed video](https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/investigations/2020/06/10/live-pd-destroyed-video-police-killing-javier-ambler-ii-2019/5332903002/) of an in-custody death.  While nothing I have read about this indicates that this wasn't in line with their contract with police, and it was after the investigation into the death was completed - it certainly adds to the negative publicity around the show.

TL;DR Making entertainment shows from live policing does not feel right to broadcasters in the current climate.